# The cmdlet Stop-Process with -Force is not working

Tags: powershell

I enter the following command in a PowerShell window:

```
(Start-Process powershell {.\scripts\skiptest\lockfile.bat} -Passthru).ID > .\pid.txt
```

Suppose the PID that got saved in pid.txt is 1234. The content of the `lockfile.bat` is:

```
@ECHO OFF

powershell.exe -command "$lock=[System.IO.File]::Open('Parse.java','Open','ReadWrite','None');Write-Host -NoNewLine 'Press any key to release the file...';$null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown')"
```

Now when I try to kill the newer PowerShell using the command:

```
Stop-Process -Force -Id 1234
```

it does not close. How can I close it?

Comment: What errors are you getting? Did you start the powershell with Run As Administrator privileges?

Comment: I sense an [X-Y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. Why are you using a PowerShell command to start a batch script to start another PowerShell command? And why are you trying to kill the parent process?

Answer (score -1):

```
$ParentPid = '1234'
$ChildProcs = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -Filter "ParentProcessID=$ParentPid" -Property ProcessId
Stop-Process -Force -id $ChildProcs.ProcessId
```

Comment: What link are you referring too?

Comment: I mean you better give more explanation than just post a code